# simple perl to iterate over hash returned from subroutine in one line?

Tags: perl, hash

Lets say I have a subroutine that returns a hash result.  I want to iterate over the key/value pair from the subroutine in my parent directory, and don't feel like saving the result to a variable first.

This seems simple, but i'm not sure how to do it at all.  If the method returns a hash I don't know the syntax required to tell the loop to expect a hash to be returned from the method.  If the method returns a hashref I can do

```
while( my($key,$value) = each ( %{ generate_hash() } )
```

but this reruns the generate_hash() method each time loop completes, regenerating the same hash, and reprocessing the first element of the hash (or at least it does in 5.10.  5.14 allows each to take a scalar which may solve the problem, not sure, but I'm limited to 5.10 sadly.

Can anyone explain what absurdly obvious syntax I'm missing here?

Comment: "and don't feel like saving the result to a variable first." This is really a poor reason for reducing the readability of your code.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this within the constrains specified. To iterate a hash you really need either `keys` or `each` and in both cases you need to 'access' the hash twice. (I suppose you could at a pinch iterate one element at a time, but then you'll still need to use a var to stick 'em together again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use List::Util 1.29 'pairs';

for my $kv ( pairs %{ genHash() } ) {
    my ($key, $value) = @$kv;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the disclaimer that the commenters are correct and that this is a bad idea, you can

1. Put the assignment inside the `%{...}` cast. Still not as readable, doesn't make the code more concise unless you can combine the `my` declaration with an earlier one:

   ```
   my $foo;
   while (my ($k,$v) = each %{$foo //= generate_hash}) { ... }
   ```
2. Make sure that `generate_hash` returns a reference to the same hash every time it is called. That way, the iterator associated with the hash will be reused and give you a new key. Of course the easiest way to accomplish this is with a variable:

   ```
   my $cached_generated_hash;
   sub generate_hash {
       return $cached_generated_hash //= do {
          ...
          { abc => 123, def => 456 }
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @mob & commenters, the following is presented for entertainment only.  Seems unproductive, though I will be interested if anyone can pull out something even remotely like an "absurdly simple syntax" to do this :-)

Oh yes, note the single invocation of genHash().

```
$ ./foo.pl
Hello from genHash()
a=beta
a=2
a=alpha
a=1
a=gamma
a=3

$ cat ./foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub genHash() {
   print "Hello from genHash()\n";
   return { alpha => 1, beta => 2, gamma => 3 };
}

# There comes a point when you have to ask
# why you are even trying to swim upstream :-)
# ----- edit as per comments to remove unnecessary reference.
# original: foreach my $a ( %${ \( genHash() ) } ) {
# ------------------------------
foreach my $x ( %{ genHash() } ) {
   print "x=", $x, "\n";
}

$
```

Comment: There's no need to take a reference and immediately dereference it, `foreach my $foo (%{genHash()}){...}` gives the same result. Note that you should never lexicalize `$a` or `$b` since they're reserved for `sort`.

Comment: cool - thanks, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - edited accordingly.  I use the %$someref routinely and didn't think to try it with just %{genHash()}